# Bing map / how to get bbox value for geoserver feature info

Tags: javascript, gis, bing-maps, geoserver, bing

Currently, I am using `bingmap` on my website.

I have been trying to get this value but I couldn't be done with this.

I would like to get `bbox` value for `Geoserver` GetFeatureInfo.

When I click on the map then I need proper value of bbox to bring `featureinfo` from `geoserver`.

I mean I would like to get `bbox` value with click event.

the value can be like this

```
-27157783.947383445,-3808292.9420554126,-27157222.897802774,-3807731.8924747426
```

Comment: when you request the wms image you are querying you will have sent a request with the bounding box, so you already have this info. We'd need to see your code to help more

Comment: Hi, how do you save shape in the geoserver?

Answer (score 1):

I use geoserver with php api and create shapes with datastores shapefiles.

In the rest, you see featureinfo in *url/workspaces/**{$workspace}**/datastores/shapefiles/featuretypes/**{$shape}**.json*

And then, with curl:

```
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{$user}:{$pass}");

        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);}

        curl_close($ch);

        $data = json_decode($result,true);
```

This work perfectly for me.

[image]

Comment: With this data(boundingBox) you can center layer.